# Inline invert boolean @click in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

For a simple demo I wanted to invert a boolean I defined inside the data property of my Vue.js instance.

What I tried:

```vue
<button @click="!spanVisible" type="button">Toggle</button>
```

and

```vue
<button @click="(!spanVisible)" type="button">Toggle</button>
```

I want to avoid either writing a separate method or having something like this inside my v-on:click="": `spanVisible ? !spanVisible : !spanVisible` because it's simply redundant.

So now my questions mostly are: Why doesn't the direct inverting work? What other possibility do I have to keep it short and simple?

**edit:**

The shortest possible variation i found right now is using `spanVisible = !spanVisible`, but not sure if that's the most concise version available.

**SOLUTION:**

The best solution I found was suggested by @Sombriks in the comments:
using `@click="!spanVisible"` only evaluates the inversed value of `spanVisible` but doesn't alternate it's value, to assign a new value to it you can use `@click="spanVisible = !spanVisible"`, which seems to be the most concise working version for now.

Comment: have you tried `!(spanVisible)`?

Comment: by just doing !spanVisible you're not changing the value, just evaluating it instead. x = !x is the way there, it's also was a valid idiom at angular1.x series.

Comment: @iHasCodeForU yeah, that's what I mentioned above, that didn't work.

Comment: @Sombriks oh damn me, how couldn't I just get that. Totally makes sense. Thanks!

Comment: Just as a sidenote, *toggle* is a more generally understood term than *invert*

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I think it is possible to do without any `methods`

Add a Click Event to reverse the value of the boolean variable. Like this:

```vue
@click="showExtra = !showExtra"
```

In your Script Data:

```vue
<script>
  export default {
  return {
    data() {
       showExtra: false
    }
 }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 6):

You are doing it wrong.
`<button v-on:click="toggle" type="button">Toggle</button>`

In your script part:

```vue
data () {
    return {
        spanVisible: true
    }
},
methods: {
    toggle () {
        this.spanVisible = !this.spanVisible
    }
}
```

Note that `data` is declared this way if you are using Vue components. If you are using in file scripting, you will skip `return`

Comment: Actuelly, the solution suggested by @Sombriks in the comments is the one I was looking for as, I needed a concise one. Your one works (if you add a comma after the data object). And that one (from @Sombriks) is also perfectly valid, as it's just an assignment expression. (Will remove the downvote as soon as corrected the missing comma)

Comment: Well, you now approved my edit as it seems, where I have added the comma ;) previously, there was still a missing comma. See http://stackoverflow.com/posts/41179971/revisions

Comment: So I would expect upvote :) 
My answer is more in line with common practice and good practice. Inline action is not what you should do with Vue

Comment: Sure, this is generally the considered better, but what I was looking for (according to the initial question) is a short and simple solution and avoiding, as specified above, separate methods. Therefor the solution in the comments is the most appropriate for this question, even though your one is generally speaking better practise.

Answer (score 1):

The key point of MVVM or MVC framework is model-driven.
`spanVisible` is one property of your model. So you need update its value directly in every handler.

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>
    export default {
        return {
            data() {
                spanVisible: false
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

@click="spanVisible ^= 1"

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).